# I am trying to install pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I downloaded pygame on the website. And went to my command prompt to pip install pygame. But it gave me this error message. metadata-generation-failed. How do I uninstall pygame and install a new version? and my version of python installed is 3.11.1

i tried to uninstall and reinstall my version of python.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall Pygame, you can use the command `pip uninstall pygame` in your command prompt. To install a new version of Pygame, you can use the command `pip install pygame==x.x.x` where `x.x.x` is the version number you want to install.

Comment: i tried downloading pygame with your method but I still got an error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: it says no "Setup" file exists so I think my problem has something to do with that.

Comment: One possible cause is that the package is not compatible with your version of Python. You mentioned that your version of Python is 3.11.1, which is not a official released version of Python. And Pygame only support up to Python 3.9

You can try installing a different version of Pygame that is compatible with your version of Python, or you can try installing Pygame from the source code rather than from a package. This may require you to have development tools like a C compiler installed on your system.

Comment: It's also possible that the package you downloaded is corrupted or incomplete, you can try downloading the package again from the official website and see if that resolves the issue.